# How do I make separated processed objects into single array with multiple object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, oop

I have an *array* of *objects*:

```
csvContent = [{
  "a": 123,
  "b": "ccc"
},
{
  "a": "bbb",
  "b": "aaa"
}];
```

I process first "a" key value to a string use

```
for (let i in csvContent){
  dataString.a = String(csvContent[i].a);
  console.log(dataString.a);
}
```

But the result from the loop is:

result on first loop is

```
{
"a": "123",
"b": "ccc"
}
```

result on second loop is

```
{
  "a": "bbb",
  "b": "aaa"
}
```

How to make those separated object back to the beginning format:

> [{},{}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

**Demo:**

```js
const csvContent = [
  { "a": 123, "b": "ccc" },
  { "a": "bbb", "b": "aaa" }
];

const res = csvContent.map(({ a, b }) => ({ a: a.toString(), b: b }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks i'm not familiar with this case and for the first time using map method

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to create separate array and convert to string and then again push. Just do like this when value is string

```
csvContent = [{
"a": 123,
"b": "ccc"
},
{
"a": "bbb",
"b": "aaa"
}]

for(let i in csvContent){
  console.log(typeof(csvContent[i].a))
 if(typeof(csvContent[i].a) != 'string'){
   csvContent[i].a = String( csvContent[i].a)
 }

}

console.log(csvContent)
```